# How to make a div to not ocuppy space?

Tags: html, css, web

I have the following.

[image]

If u see, the "asdasdasd" text is not near the top of the div.
I have a div with two divs inside

```
<div id="widget">
<div id="header"> </div> 
<div id="content"> </div>
</div>
```

The header div have a fixed height, and this background image.

[image]

If you see what is in red, that part of the background make me need the div to be bigger, but it moves the content div down.

I tried to pull it up using margin-bottom: -Ypx; but I think its a ugly fix. I can't find something that works for me.

somebody can help (:?

Comment: Can you show some HTML/CSS code that reproduces the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah you can use the `position:absolute` to keep out the div header you need this properties:

```
#widget {
  position:relative;
}
```

<sub>Make the parent relative, that way the position absolute of the header will be relative to this container</sub>

```
#header {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}
```

<sub>Position absolute to the top ande left of his container</sub>

Comment: wow, it works really nice, thanks Danko. some time ago i didn't like positioning, but in the last time i'm using them more and more, i should spend some time and learn their tricks.

Comment: yep position brings you more posibilities :) glad to help you